# bootstrap font icons does not appear

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have created small preview. I kept twitter and retweet icons at line 11 & 12 in fiddle. Why icons does not appear?

code:

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/JqN64/3/)

```
    <div class="item">
        <div class="image"> 
            <img class="media-object" src="http://deathandtaxesmag.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Screen-Shot-2014-02-27-at-12.39.17-PM.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionContainer">
            <span class="main-head"> Mashable - Business </span>
            <span class="min-head">Title of link</span>
            <span class="subcont">
                    <span class="icon-retweet">Retweet 100+</span> 
                    <span class="icon-twitter-sign">Retweet 100+</span> 
            </span>
        </div>  
    </div>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **old syntax** where classes were defined using `icon-` as the prefix, but now since version 4.0, Font Awesome uses `fa-` prefix, also it requires an additional `class` of `fa` to be declared with the icon.

So this <s>`icon-retweet`</s> should be `fa fa-retweet`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JqN64/4/)